# Can I transfer my Australian visa to a new passport if it has a different name?

Tags: visas, australia

I got a visitor visa for Australia and now I want to change my name from my maiden to my husband's. Is it possible to transfer my visa to my new passport,or should I cancel my visa while I change my name?

Comment: This may help https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/change-in-situation

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can transfer an Australian visa to a new passport with a change of name.  You can do so via ImmiAccount or Form 929 as set out on [the Department's web site](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/change-in-situation/passport-details).

In particular, the instructions to [Form 929](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/form-listing/forms/929.pdf) provide the following:

> **Change of name in passport**
>
> Where a new passport has been issued with a new name, you should provide certified copies of the Bio-data page of the previous passport, new passport and official evidence of name change (eg. change of name certificate, marriage certificate) with this form in order for the Department to confirm your identity.
>
> If you have an endorsement in your current passport with your new name as the principal name, you need to provide certified copies of relevant pages of the current passport and official evidence of name change with this form in order for the Department to confirm your identity.